# AWS:EC2 enable dns-hostname for host in non default vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpc

I have a non-default vpc where i want to launch instances.
The docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html say:

Non-default vpc: "DNS hostnames are disabled by default."

Currently there is no option to set in during ec2-launch with "aws ec2 run-instances".

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html

Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

To enable DNS resolution and DNS hostnames for your VPC, open the **VPC Management Console** > **Your VPCs**. Click on your VPC and then click on **Actions** and then enable both **Edit DNS Resolution** & **Edit DNS Hostnames**.

[image]

Comment: When this option is disabled, would this prevent dns resolution within the VPC?

Comment: If either or both of the attributes is set to false, the following occurs:
>Instances with a public IP address do not receive corresponding public DNS hostnames.
>The Amazon-provided DNS server cannot resolve Amazon-provided private DNS hostnames.
>Instances receive custom private DNS hostnames if there is a custom domain name in the DHCP options set. If you are not using the Amazon-provided DNS server, your custom domain name servers must resolve the hostname as appropriate.

Comment: I'm facing some issues with private DNS, when I `dig` any address within the VPC (non-default), I don't get a `answer section`. I've tried to resolve the names from the  default VPC, and I works. I've read in some AWS articles that I can't prevent DNS server access by Security Groups, ACL ou prevent routes to it. But what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

DNS resolution is on a per-VPC basis, not per-instance. You can enable DNS hostnames by finding the VPC in the VPC management console and Enabling DNS hostname support.

[image]